# AngularJS - Passing variable to controller

Tags: angularjs, routes

I need to send a parameter to the controller

```
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider

        .when('/url-1', {
            parameter: 1
        })

        .when('/url-2', {
            parameter: 2
        })

        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/url-1'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: true
    });
}
```

this is my controller

```
function MyController(parameter) {

    console.log(parameter);

}
```

and in the view I only have two links

```
<a ng-href="/url-1">url-1</a>
<a ng-href="/url-2">url-1</a>
```

Do I need to specify the controller in the $routeProvider?
I only have one controller. I´m not loading views dinamically 
I just need to do a console.log(parameter) based on the parameter sent by $routeProvider

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This would be good way to define route, suppose if you have 100 routes then the rout definition would get increased to that number. Rather that multiple routes have single generic route.

And assign a controller to the route where you can access $routeParams API to get parameters available in route.

Config

```
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider
    .when('/url/:id', {
        controller: MyController
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/url/1'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: true
    });
}
```

Controller

```
function MyController($routeParams) {
    console.log($routeParams);
}
```

---

If you don't want to place another controller's for each route then you can keep track of route changes by placing hook on `routeChangeSuccess` event inside run block of your application like below

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $routeParams ) {
     $rootScope.$on('routeChangeSuccess', function() {
        console.log($routeParams);
     }
});
```

OR you can have that event inside page controller which has been placed on body.

```
function MyController($scope, $routeParams) {
    console.log("Parameters on page load "+ $routeParams);
    $scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, next, current) {
       console.log($routeParams);
    }
}
```

Comment: I only have 2 routes and i´m already calling my controller in the view with <html ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController as vm">

Comment: Follow the approach that I suggested as it would be more scalable. So now if you don't want to assign controller per route, you can have hook on `$routeChangeSuccess` event

Comment: thank you so much for your suggestion. is not clear to me why I need to assign a controller per route because all URLs are going to the same (and only) If I´ma lready calling the controller in the view. what´s the effect of doing the same in the $routeProvider?

Comment: @handsome controller is needed for each route to maintain separation of concern in your application, if you are only going to use `single` controller per application it is going to clutter down your controller with 2k-3k lines, and it would be really challenging to maintain such code, so its good practice to follow separate controller for separate route/component

Comment: 2k-3k lines? we need to focus on this problem. I only need to respond to changes in the URL. The controller is always the same I just want to console.log('you are coming from url-1, 2, etc') I do appreciate your design suggestion which is the right one but for applications like the ones you described. thanks again!

Comment: @handsome that's what I had in my other part of an answer, you can try that as well..

Answer (score 0):

```
function config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

$routeProvider

    .when('/url-1', {
        params: {id : 1}
    })

    .when('/url-2', {
        params: {id : 2}
    })

    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/url-1'
    });

$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: true
});
```

}

```
function MyController($routeParams) {
console.log($routeParams);
```

}

Comment: I don´t see any changes when I click the links. :(